# How do I write a one-line generator for this Python 3.x list cycle?

Tags: python, list, cycle

How to make a generator of this cycle correctly?

I am a novice programmer, do not judge strictly, the Mentor asks me to write this cycle in one line

```
for post in posts:
    post_id_detail[post['id']] = post
```

I do this but it doesn't work

```
post = [post_id_detail[post['id']] for post in posts]
```

Help to make the right generator in one line

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour]. Never write just "it does not work", it does not say much useful. Write what actually happens. Is there any specific error message or are the results incorrwct?

Comment: Welcome to SO ! what is `post_id_detail`, `post`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`post_id_detail` is apparently a dict rather than a list, so use a dict comprehension instead:

```
post_id_detail = {post['id']: post for post in posts}
```